# Google App Scripts what is a 'paged' call?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

What is a 'paged' call?

It is mentioned all over this page https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app.html#search(String)

Is there any documentation of what a 'paged' call is? Why do they refer to it like it is something I should be able to read about somewhere else?

It says seven times

> please use the 'paged' call, and specify ranges of the threads to
>   retrieve in each call.

I understand the concept of breaking it into pieces but they are saying **the** 'paged' call is there some documentation on this or some sort of slang I am supposed to understand?

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55722600/how-to-read-all-mails-from-inbox-in-google-script)

Comment: @Cooper Yes I saw that question, which is actually what prompted me to ask this question, because I never noticed the documentation in 7 places on one page mentions this phrase. Is there an official definition of what a 'paged' call is somewhere? Is this just some sort of programmer slang I am supposed to know about or is there some references online to what exactly `THE 'paged' call` is?

Comment: Use the search for duplicate questions and search with `[google-apps-script] 'paged' call`

Comment: A lot of times you have to use page tokens when searching through collections and I think that's what they're talking about.  I didn't know what was either.

Comment: @Cooper yes this is how I came about to asking this question, I know it is mentioned in many questions but no one ever defines what exactly a 'paged' call is? I mean I get the concept of how to solve those particular issues, but they are talking about it like it is some sort of official thing, so I guess the question is this just a figure of speech `programmer slang` or is there actually documentation somewhere anywhere of what a `paged call` is, maybe there is a paged call function we don't know about or maybe I can find paged call on slang dictionary.

Comment: @Cooper right, I feel like when reading the documentation and you see something official like this, it is talking about something you would expect there to be a paragraph explaining what it is the concept and maybe examples of what paged calls are, because it makes me think there is a paged call function somewhere.

Comment: For a code example showing a paged call, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55723614/771768

Answer (score 2):

This is referring to the concept of a Page Token, you should be able to add it as a parameter to your requests. There's some better examples [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/gmail#list_inbox_snippets). Unfortunately, there's no page that really explains what a page token is so I'll try my best.

Let's say I call the Gmail API and I want a list of all emails in my account. That's too much to deliver in one request, so I ask for 1,000 at a time, starting from my most recent messages. When I request 1,000 messages, Google will return a `page token` to me along with the 1,000 results I asked for. If I want the 1,000 next most recent emails, I need to send the `pageToken` I got from my previous request with my new request.

Think of it like flipping through a book, where you get to decide how many "words" are on a page (using the `maxResults` parameter). When you stop getting a pageToken back from Google, you're at the end of the book and have requested all available information.

`pageToken` only seems to be available on the [Gmail Advanced Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).

Comment: Where is the documentation for pageToken in the Gmail Advanced Service link? Also I can't seem to find an API for the Drive... Gmail... advanced objects?

Comment: Check [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list#parameters).

Comment: Linking the *REST* API with a `string` token isn't very helpful, because the question is about paged API calls to the google App Scripts javascript API which uses a `Number` token.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO the pragmatic interpretation of

> Where the thread size is unknown, and potentially very large, please use the 'paged' call, and specify ranges of the threads to retrieve in each call.

is to use [search(query, start, max)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app.html#searchquery,-start,-max) instead of `query(query)`

---

While understanding each technical term might be very helpful, it's more important to interpret them considering the whole statement and context.